# I changed the Button text (in Code) and when I click on him is back to the default text iOS

Tags: ios, button, methods, return

I made 2 buttons (A and B). and when i click on B button, the A button text is change to C text, and thats work but when i click Button A (Thats now C) After i change the text, its back to A...
look:
when i Press B button thats the method that happen:

```
- (IBAction)onClickAnswer:(id)sender {
A.titleLabel.text = @"C"; // A button set B text
}
```

when i click on B button A button Text changing to C, and when i Click A button after i change the text(C button) its return to A.. 
why that happen?

Comment: Any Actions for the button A? This can be caused by the highlighted (or selected) state text of `Button A` set to `@"A"`, and in the action (or routine) for Button A, you are changing the state. Need more code to understand.

Comment: Did you figure this out? If so, please accept my answer below and close this question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I see two most likely problems with this code.

1. You should definitely use [`setTitle:forState:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle:forState:) method when setting a title to UIButton:

   `[A setTitle:@"C" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`
2. Check if your IBAction methods are connected with correct buttons.